# Javascript: Math.random() variable changes each time the variable is referenced?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

```
var slaying = true;
var youHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
var damageThisRound = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
var totalDamage = 0;

while(slaying){
    if(youHit){
        console.log("You slice the dragon!")
        totalDamage += damageThisRound;
        if(totalDamage>=4){
            console.log("Dragon is deafeated!");
            slaying=false;
        }
        var youHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    }else{
        console.log("Dragon is too strong for you. Defeated.")
        slaying=false;
    }
}
```

This is a short program on a tutorial for Javascript. However, I don't see how damageThisRound would ever change value.

It is initialised at the top with the Math methods. Then we start the game in the While loop, where the value of damageThisRound never changes. Obviously it should change each time we loop (for each 'round' or 'hit') but nothing changes it within the loop. Am I missing something here?

Comment: What makes you think it changes?

Comment: It doesn't change. It's a poor tutorial if it is supposed to change with the provided code. Maybe it should be changed like `youHit` is? (And ditch the `var` inside the loop..)

Comment: I'm confused -- are you asking why it doesn't change, or how to make it change?

Comment: Clearly it /should/ change as each 'hit' should do different damage- it's even named 'damageThisRound', implying that it will change with each 'round' or 'hit'. So I am correct in thinking that the code does not change the damageThisRound for each round?

Comment: @blueplancha You are correct, it does not change. Do you want to know how to make it change?

Comment: No thanks, I could do that easily. Surprisingly poor for Codecademy. Thanks

Comment: I don't have enough rep to close the question apparently..

Comment: When you set a variable using random() it will give that variable a random value, if you want this random value to be random each time you use the variable then place it inside of your for loop as it won't just call the existing value but it will run random() again. So what is the point of this question because I don't understand the question..... Could **anyone** point it out please?

Comment: The point was- this was prewritten code in a tutorial. As damageEachRound should change with each 'hit', I couldn't see where/how it was changing with each loop, so I came here to ask how it was changing, if at all. However, as users have stated  here, the program does not change the damageEachRound as it should.

Comment: Yes..... and you have already said you know how to change it so what is the problem? You knew the source code was wrong and you have already claimed you know how to fix it when someone asked you if you wanted to know how to change it.....

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the code. The "damageThisRound" is set once at the beginning to some random value, and is applied to the total damage each iteration. The "youHit" variable is the one that is re-calculated each interval to see whether or not you hit and apply the "damageThisRound" value to the total damage. It's basically a 50/50 calculation per iteration to hit.